# Question on a hypothetical equation of state

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

Suppose that there exists an equation of state given by $PV=ST$ ( Notice that the units are correct). What would be the implication of this? Is there something that prohibits this from being true? Please let me know.

Comment: Welcome to this community! It'd be good if you explained your symbols. Would "$S$" be the entropy?

Comment: just the usual variables, Pressure, Volume, Entropy and Temperature.

Comment: Is this something you just made up?

Comment: @BobD yes it is

Answer (score 2):

Your equation
$$PV=ST$$

pass the criterion to be a state equation. But I can't say that such a system does exist or not. I have added implication in the last. In sort

---

The third law of thermodynamics states as follows, regarding the properties of closed systems in thermodynamic equilibrium:

```
The entropy of a system approaches a constant value as its temperature approaches absolute zero.
```

Your equation disagrees with this.

---

**Reasons for passing as state** :

An equation of state is a thermodynamic equation relating to state variables that describe the state of matter under a given set of physical conditions, such as pressure, volume, temperature ($PVT$), or internal energy.

---

The number of state variables required to specify the [thermodynamic state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_state) depends on the system, and is not always known in advance of the experiment; it is usually found from experimental evidence. Always the number is two or more; usually it is not more than some dozen. Though the number of state variables is fixed by experiment, there remains the choice of which of them to use for a particular convenient description; a given thermodynamic system may be alternatively identified by several different choices of the set of state variables.

---

The relationship expressed as increments of entropy equal to the ratio of incremental heat transfer divided by temperature, which was found to vary in the thermodynamic cycle but eventually returns to the same value at the end of every cycle. Thus it was found to be a function of the state, specifically a thermodynamic state of the system.

---

*Is entropy of all systems zero at absolute zero?*

Not quite. Some systems can be in their ground state and still have a nontrivial state.
But It's possible! (at least as an approximation) Per the definition, a perfect crystal at $0 K$ would have an entropy $S=0$.

---

**Implications**

Such a system seems to be impossible (or highly improbable) due to reason of the defining properties of entropy

$$S=k_B\ln\Omega$$

as you know that you would expect the number of states will increase if you increase the temperature and so the entropy but your formula suggest that If you kept $PV$ to be constant
$$S\propto \frac{1}{T}$$

which is not physically possible!

The third law of thermodynamics states as follows, regarding the properties of closed systems in thermodynamic equilibrium:

```
The entropy of a system approaches a constant value as its temperature approaches absolute zero.
```

Your equation disagrees with this.

Comment: thank you @Young Kindaichi, that was the answer I was looking for.

Comment: I have another question, is it possible to keep pressure and volume constant while changing the temperature experimentally? Sorry if I'm being noobish, I'm not a physicist. @Young Kindaichi

Comment: No, You see most of the system the equation of state is a function of pressure, volume, and temperature. If you fix any two of them the third one gets a fix. So you only allowed varying two of them at a time.

Comment: So, wouldn't this imply that the case where S is proportional to 1/T is never true? @Young Kindaichi

Comment: As I said for most of the cases, it might possible to have a state equation depending on the system with dozen of variables then you can vary many of them at a time. In your case, there are 4 of them, so can vary 3 of them at a time. What makes your equation unphysical is the third law and other associated laws.

Comment: Is it wrong to say that , for S=PV/T, the decrease in temperature towards absolute zero could be compensated by a decrease in either P or V, therefore not necessarily violating the third law? @Young Kindaichi

Comment: You might but the fact is the third law must be valid in all cases. I can choose PV to be constant and then the third law gets violated.

Comment: @YoungKindaichi, your argument neglects the dependence of $S$ on the number of molecules. According to your argument, even the perfect gas equation of state should be wrong since it says that $N=\frac{PV}{k_BT}$. Therefore you should conclude in a similar way that it is impossible that the number of particles at fixed $PV$ decreases with the temperature.

Comment: yeah, @GiorgioP definitely has a point. I'm treating S as a function of U,N and V by the way.

Comment: I'm considering a system with no exchange of mass. So no talk about chemical potential or anything. Besides, I'm not going to get into what will go wrong I just give one law that gets violated.  Any law that takes this law as the base will also get violated.

Comment: If OP is asking for whole changes in theory that will be made through this equation is kind of hard to tell and will be the whole theory in a way. That should be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that PV is constant, then the entropy S would decrease with the increase of temperature. That's completely erroneous, due to the fact that increasing the temperature, decrease entropy. Plus, if entropy decrease with the increase of temperature, the equipartition of energy would tear apart.

Comment: But is it possible, experimentally, to keep pressure and volume constant while changing the temperature? @Almighty